# CCleaner installation startup issue

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ccleaner

Ii have upgraded my CCleaner to 5.18.5607 from earlier version 5.07.5261. My windows is Windows XP SP3.

The Active Monitoring, Browser Monitoring & System Monitoring under settings are completely disabled.

But upon start CCleaner installer keeps on running despite disabling all startup entries and configurations / settings in CCleaner.

Kindly help me in fixing it. I want the installer to stop running at startup.
Attached is the image.[image: CCleaner]

I also get this nss3.dll error messages but its not everytime. But the setup keeps on running everytime which is quite frustrating and annoying for me.

Comment: When does it ran precisely, update question, a comment won't be read.

Comment: Have you tried what it said "reinstall"?

Comment: Have you uninstalled completely, reboot, then reinstall?